# Pygame sprite.collide_circle seems to be using a circumscribed circle, I want inscribed

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

In looking at the circle collisions, I copied the code and then fixed a few things and modified the code to see the rects of the sprites.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((250, 250))

sprite1 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
sprite1.image = pygame.Surface((80, 80), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(sprite1.image, (255, 0, 0), (40, 40), 40)
sprite1.rect = pygame.Rect(*window.get_rect().center, 0, 0).inflate(80, 80) 
#sprite1.rect = pygame.Rect(*sprite1.rect).inflate(-23.44,-23.44)
sprite2 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
sprite2.image = pygame.Surface((80, 80), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(sprite2.image, (0, 255, 0), (40, 40), 40)  
sprite2.rect = pygame.Rect(125, 125, 0, 0).inflate(80, 80) 

all_group = pygame.sprite.Group([sprite2, sprite1])
test_group = pygame.sprite.Group(sprite2)

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    sprite1.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite1, test_group, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

    window.fill(0)
    all_group.draw(window)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,255,255), sprite1.rect, 1)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,255,255), sprite2.rect, 1)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255), sprite1.rect.center, 56.5, 1)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255), sprite2.rect.center, 56.5, 1)
    for s in collide:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255), s.rect.center, s.rect.width // 2, 5)
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

What I expected was for the collide_circle routine to use the inscribed (red and green) circles in the rect as the sprite boundaries since those are the sprites.  Instead, it is using a circle that has the rect inscribed within it (a bigger circle drawn as a white ring around the rects).  This is evidenced by the green circle getting a white border when the collision is true.

Initially I thought I could just make the rect smaller so that it is inside the sprite circle, but that doesn't work because it then offsets the sprite when drawn.

At the end of the day, I expect to use masks, but this example is bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

See [`pygame.sprite.collide_circle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

> [...] If the sprites have a "radius" attribute, that is used to create the circle, otherwise a circle is created that is big enough to completely enclose the sprites rect as given.

So the `collide_circle` uses a circle big enough to enclose the complete rectangle (`rect`) of the sprite. You have to set the `radius` attribute:

```py
sprite1 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
sprite1.image = pygame.Surface((80, 80), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(sprite1.image, (255, 0, 0), (40, 40), 40)
sprite1.rect = pygame.Rect(*window.get_rect().center, 0, 0).inflate(80, 80) 
sprite1.radius = 40

sprite2 = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
sprite2.image = pygame.Surface((80, 80), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(sprite2.image, (0, 255, 0), (40, 40), 40)  
sprite2.rect = pygame.Rect(125, 125, 0, 0).inflate(80, 80) 
sprite2.radius = 40
```